# Issue looping through websites

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Trying to loop through multiple pages of one website. I can scrape one page, but i can't figure out how to replace whats in the brackets in the URL with the items in the list.

```
URL = "https://www.samplebooks.com/&s={}&1000"
BList = ["28", "9", "10", "14", "6", "13", "30", "29", "1", "24", "27"]
Statement = []
html_text = requests.get(Statement).text
Soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "lxml")
Books = Soup.find_all("tr")
for output in BList:
    Statement.append(URL.format(output))
    for things in Books:
        print((things.text))
```

Comment: Your Statement list is working as intended. ['https://www.samplebooks.com/&s=28&1000', 'https://www.samplebooks.com/&s=9&1000', 'https://www.samplebooks.com/&s=10&1000',.........]. Isn't that what you're looking for?

Comment: Is it working as intended? I keep getting error messages when i run it.

Comment: As i rebuild this line by line, It looks like the .get portion of the code is not working for some reason. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're creating the statement array correctly, but you are not using the array after filling it up.

This might be what you're looking for

```
for output in BList:

    # add the URL to the array
    Statement.append(URL.format(output))
    
    # Statement[-1] is the last element in the array (most recent element)
    html_text = requests.get(Statement[-1]).text
    Soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "lxml")
    Books = Soup.find_all("tr")
    for things in Books:
        print((things.text))
```

Comment: This is the error i just got:
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 384, in prepare_url
    scheme, auth, host, port, path, query, fragment = parse_url(url)
  , line 394, in parse_url
    return six.raise_from(LocationParseError(source_url), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
urllib3.exceptions.LocationParseError: Failed to parse: []

Answer (score 0):

*Without any additional information it is hard to give a concrete answer, so it would be great to improve your question.*

**There are two things I would like to highlight:**

1. URL parameters (also known as *query strings*) are initiated by a question mark `?` and not by separator symbol `&`
2. It do not need a list called `Statement` simply iterate the `BList` and request it directly like:
   `requests.get(URL.format(output)).text`

##### Example

*Code only works if you replace example url part `https://www.samplebooks.com/` with correct url and if there are `<tr>` in HTML response*

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

URL = "https://www.samplebooks.com/?s={}&1000"
BList = ["28", "9", "10", "14", "6", "13", "30", "29", "1", "24", "27"]

for b in BList:
    html_text = requests.get(URL.format(b)).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text)
    books = soup.find_all("tr")
    for things in books:
        print((things.text))
```